# How do I "make a deal with the devil"?

Tags: the-binding-of-isaac

How exactly do I make a deal with the devil? I'm trying to unlock Eve (the one with the dead bird).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sometimes, when you defeat a boss, an extra black door will open up in the boss room that leads to the [Devil Room](http://bindingofisaac.wikia.com/wiki/Devil_Room). In that room, you can trade heart containers for items, like how you can trade coins for items in stores. "Making a deal with the devil" is trading for an item in the devil room.

Comment: The wiki page this answer links to shows you the ways to increase the odds of getting a Devil Room. The two ways I find most convenient are killing Beggars, and avoiding red heart damage during the boss fight.

Comment: Additionally, owning holy or devil items will themselves make Devil Rooms more likely - scapular, mitre, halo, pentagram, book of belial, etc. There's also something like a 35% reduced chance to see it twice in a row or something to that effect.